# How does MS Access save dates

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Does MS Access save dates the same way that Excel does, by using a serial number in the background? I have been searching the MS website to find this information but have found nothing on this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/210276/how-to-store,-calculate,-and-compare-date-time-data-in-microsoft-access

> Access stores the Date/Time data type as a double-precision, floating-point number up to 15 decimal places. The integer part of the double-precision number represents the date. The decimal portion represents the time.
>
> Valid date values range from -657,434 (January 1, 100 A.D.) to 2,958,465 (December 31, 9999 A.D.). A date value of 0 represents December 30, 1899. Access stores dates before December 30, 1899 as negative numbers.
>
> Valid time values range from .0 (00:00:00) to .99999 (23:59:59). The numeric value represents a fraction of one day. You can convert the numeric value to hours, to minutes, and to seconds by multiplying the numeric value by 24.